# What are the ten most commonly used NSString methods?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, methods, nsstring

I was wondering what are some of the most used and "essential" NSString methods to learn. Obviously I can't remember all of them off by heart so I was just wondering what are the most commonly used ones?

Answer (score 2):

This question is entirely too subjective.  The most commonly used NSString methods in my apps aren't necessarily going to be the most commonly used applications in *your* apps.

That said, get to know the documentation in the Xcode organizer.  It'll quickly become your best friend (along with the "`.h`" header files hidden within the Xcode SDK packages).

My own most frequently used NSString methods probably include:

```
stringWithFormat:
substringFromIndex:
initWithData:encoding:
initWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:
length
stringByAppendingFormat:
compare:options:
```

Answer (score 1):

I find it's easier to learn when you have a specific goal.

That being said, here are some common ones:

```
myString = [NSString stringWithString:@"LOL! BBQ! ROFL!"];
int length = [myString length];
myString = [myString characterAtIndex:7];
myString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"LOL" withString:@"ROFL"];
mystring = [myString lowercaseString];
int seven = [myString integerValue]; // converts @"7" into the integer 7.
```

You can peruse the [whole list here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).